# using or operator while running commands in background

Tags: bash

I'm using following command without any problem:

```
echo "some code" > example && somecommand example || othercommand example
```

But when I want to run `somecommand` and `othercommand` in background something like this:

```
echo "some code" > example && somecommand example & || othercommand example &
```

I get following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Drop the `&` before the `||`. Also, note that `&&` and `||` do not run stuff in the background, but sequentially (if at all). Do you want an `and`-`or` scheme, or just to run everything?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to run your complete [list of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) in background, you can [group them](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) as a compound command `{ cmd1 || cmd2; }` or `(cmd1 || cmd2)` and then run that compound command in background:

```
{ echo "some code" > example && somecommand example || othercommand example; } &
```

or

```
(echo "some code" > example && somecommand example || othercommand example) &
```

Note that you can't run commands in background *and* wait on them with `&&`/`||` operators (bash man, [Lists section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists)):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell. This is known as executing the command in the background. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0 (true).

To wait for a background process, you can use [`wait` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Builtins) command.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to combine these constructs.  The `||` and `&&` operators (obviously) need to wait for the previous command to finish in order to examine whether it was successful or not.